# How to sort on date columns in jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, sorting, date, datatables

I am trying to figure out how to sort columns of date type.

There are some plugins available but I don't see any plugin which supports mm/dd/yyyy date format. Is there any built-in support for this?

I was thinking is if can we supply an alternate column value for sorting, then I will retain timestamp value and it can automatically get sorted as its numeric.

**Update:**

I tried sending timestamp from the server and format in `mRender` like this

```
"mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
    return moment(+data).format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a");
}
```

But still sorting doesn't seem to happen on number (timestamp)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about whether or not there are any plugins, but you can create a custom sort.

You can set the [sType](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns#sType) of the column and then implement a [custom sorting function](http://www.datatables.net/development/sorting#type_based).

Answer (score 0):

the default sort cannot correctly handle the same day data, like this :

```
"order": [
    [0, "desc"]
],
```

you can try [this](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18) or rendering tables  after sorted data. another way is sort the data on the server